# Add objects for NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSMutableArray` with a lot of objects. What i want is, insert at first 3 positions (indexes) new objects, and, move other objects indexes accordingly.

For example, i have `NSMutableArray` with objects: obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4.

I want to make modify my array, so it look like follow: newObj1, newObj2, newObj3, obj1, obj2, obj3.

Im afraid, if i use `[myMutableArray insertObject:myObject atIndex:0];` i will replay my obj1 with newObj1, therefore it would be something like: newObj1, newObj2, newObj3, obj4, obj5...

How could i achieve my point?

Comment: Have you tried using `insertObject:atIndex:`? You might be pleased with the results. From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/insertObject:atIndex:): "If index is already occupied, the objects at index and beyond are shifted by adding 1 to their indices to make room."

Comment: you'll not replace your old objects, they will be shifted as you want

Comment: @originaluser2 okay, thank you :)

Comment: Note that there's a completely different method for replacing objects, `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:`

Comment: @originaluser2 okay, thank you again a lot!

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban happy to help, although you should always have a read up on the documentation of a method before posting a question about it.

Comment: @originaluser2 yeah, my bad, sorry.

Comment: `[myMutableArray insertObject:myObject atIndex:0];` is perfect for that, you already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will not replace your object.
it will behave as what you are expecting  so just put that code

Answer (score 1):

`insertObject:atIndex:` this method is used for inserting an object at a specified index and if an object exists at that index then the existing object will be moved to next index (not replace an object) and new object is added.

`replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:` this method actually replaces an old object with new one.